# RxJava - fetch every item on the list and emits one-by-one (any order)

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a method that returns an `Observable<List<Long>>`, which are ids of some Items. I'd like to go through this list and download every Item using another method that returns `Observable<Item>`. currently I'm doing it by below code.

```
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Item>> getResponses(List<Long> requests) {
        return Observable.from(requests).
                flatMap((Func1<Long, Observable<Item>>) restRequest -> getResponseEach(restRequest)).toList();
    }
```

It's working fine, but it returning all the response in on go, I mean when all download get finish then my `onNext()` get invoked,

**Main Question** But alternatively I need to emit every response one-by-one(Any Order) once each item fetched successfully from server, so my `onNext` should be invoked every-time time individually for each item.

How would I do this using RxJava operators?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `toList()` operator. The `toList()` will emit only after all the emissions of the upstream have been completed, and it will collect the results and will emit as a `Single<List<YourResultObject>>`

You can return the observable returned by the `flatMap` in your code and you will get the results one by one,

```
public Observable<Item> getResponses(List<Long> requests) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(requests)
            .flatMap(restRequest -> getResponseEach(restRequest));
 }
```

Now, your `getResponses` method will return `Observable<Item>` instead of `Observable<List<Item>>`

And you can subscribe to this function as follows

```
    getResponses(ids)
           .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Item>() {
               @Override
               public void onNext(Item item) {
                   // each item will be received here one by one
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   // handle any occured error during the operation
               }

               @Override
               public void onComplete() {
                   // all operations completed
               } 
           });
```

Comment: your `getResponseEach` returns `Observable<Item>`  right?

Comment: yes, but instead of `Observable.fromIterable` I'm using `Observable.from()`, just bcoz `fromIterable` in available.

Comment: You are using Rxjava 1 or 2

Comment: I'm using RxJava 1

Comment: Okay, then use `from` instead of `fromIterable`. `fromIterable` introduced in Rxjava 2

Comment: Can you explain what error or what result are you getting